# Kendo grid - on hover color change not working in Google chrome alone

Tags: css, google-chrome, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc

In my kendo grid, i have implemented on hover color change by including the below css code which was suggested in one of the telerik forums.

```
.k-grid table tr:hover {
    background :rgb(107, 188, 242) !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

This works perfectly fine in IE browsers, But in google chrome the color partially gets retained when i hover from one row to another(attached image). What mite have been possibly gone wrong here?

[image]

Thanks,
Adarsh

Comment: Which OS/Chrome versions are you using? I've tried to reproduce it here (http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/b8fpw/) and works fine in my chrome / latest KendoUI release

Comment: Hmm, its Win 7 / Version 35.0.1916.114 m of chrome, latest version I believe

Comment: Did you try the link that I sent and see if it fails too?

Comment: Yea, i tried that, it works fine! Im not sure, I even tried having all my custom css related to grid in fiddle, still it works fine here, Im not sure whats going wrong in my app!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly, when I apply a hover to the td like below, it worked fine!

```
.k-grid table tr:hover td {
    background :rgb(107, 188, 242) !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```